# Creating a dynamic array for a set

Tags: c

I need to create the following:
A generic finite but dynamic set, initialized to hold any number of items of any kind 
without any particular order and no repeated values.

So I started by creating a struct which holds an array (which is basically the set) and the set's name:

```
typedef struct set{

    char name; /* A unique identifier for every set */
    int value[]; /* A dynamic array of integers; the set */

} Set;
```

I put this in a header file to serve as an interface.

I am now stuck at the implementation level. I need to create a function, basically:

```
create()
```

However, I'm not sure how to make the value[] a dynamic array. I know I have to use malloc, but I'm kind of confused.

I tried this code to no avail:

```
Set * create()
{
    Set S;
    int n;
    int * ptd;

    S.value * ptd = (int *) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "I tried this code to no avail". What was wrong with it? Compilation errors? Different results than expected?

Comment: What's the value of `n`? If `n` is 0, then `n * anything` is zero, and `malloc` **may** return `NULL`. Another problem is that your `create` function does not return any value. To return a valid `Set *`, you'd have to allocate the `Set` itself in the heap using `malloc` rather than allocating it in the stack automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redefine set to have a dynamic pointer:

```
typedef struct set{

    char name; /* A unique identifier for every set */
    int *value; /* A dynamic array of integers; the set */
    int numberOfValues; /* The number of actual values currently in the set */
    int sizeOfArray; /* The number of elements allocated (must be >= numberOfValues) */

} Set;
```

`create` needs a return value, and it needs to also dynamically allocate the set structure itself. Modify `create` as follows:

```
Set * create()
{
    Set *S;

    S = malloc(sizeof(Set));
    S->name = NULL;
    S->numberOfValues = 0;
    S->sizeOfArray = 32;
    S->value = malloc(S.sizeOfArray * sizeof(int));
    return S;
}
```

Every time you add something to a set, you will have to check if `S.sizeOfArray` is large enough to contain the new element. If not, you will have to reallocate `S.value` and store the new size in `S.sizeOfArray`. Also, make sure you increment `S.numberOfValues` every time you add an element to the set!

Answer (score 0):

Why not declare `int*` itself in struct?

```
int *value; /* A dynamic array of integers; the set */
```

And allocate memory using ..

```
S.value =malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Incomplete. That is not the only problem.

Comment: @MadPhysicist what else we need to complete it? I also have allocated as described later..

Comment: `S.value * ptd = (int *) malloc(n * sizeof(int));` won't compile

Comment: @MadPhysicist yea I noticed that... That's why changed my code immediately.. Thanks..

Answer (score -1):

To create a dynamic array you have to use a pointer array just as you create a string. A string is basically a dynamic array of char, so you can do something like char* msg = "Hello". The same applies to int. To control that no element is repeated in the structure you have to implement a Contains method and Add if !Contains(x).